# How do i load the series data based on mouse scroll event highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have 200 bar series on highcharts, Due to that when i scrolling the mouse, highcharts not loading properly,Hence i want to load the chart series based on the scroll event in highcharts.

```
        xAxis: {

                events: {
                   setExtremes: function (e) {
                    if (e.trigger === 'scrollbar') {                        
                       I want to load the data series here based on scroll
                    }
                },



                }
            },
```

I tried this code is working, but dont know how to load the chart data based on scroll. Please help if anyone knows.

Comment: Hi user2703151, Please provide us with more detailed description of your problem. In what context you use the code you that added? Also a live example would be very useful.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for the response, I edited my question. Actually I want to load the data series based on scroll, Now i have 170 data series like [40,20,30.....] and so on, Due to huge series when i scroll the mouse chart is hanging.

Comment: Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hzd5x6a4/ - if you move the scrollbar to the right edge, new points will be added to the chart. Let me know if you wanted such a solution.